# Synthesised properties for primitive data types using ARC -- weak or assign?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I was wondering what is the correct way to write synthesised properties for primitive data types (like `bool`) when ARC is enabled.

I used to use this before ARC:

```
@property(assign) bool isOn;
```

But it is my understanding (maybe wrong) that you shouldn't use `assign` when ARC is enabled. I tried replacing this with `weak` but I get the error -

> Property of "weak" attribute must be of type object.

Should I continue to use `assign`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Assign` is fine. ARC stands for "Automatic Reference Counting", and primitive data types do not have reference counts.

`Weak` failed because there is no object, nor any references for ARC to manage.

Comment: so assign is not a perfect synonym for weak then. but then again, weak is default right?

Comment: "Assign is fine" I keep reading that. It has a nice rhyme to it, but it seems to evade the point: Is "assign" necessary!? What happens if you don't use "assign"?

Comment: "Assign" is the default if you don't specify the setter semantic yourself. `@property bool isOn` is the same as `@property (assign) bool isOn`. See [Obj C Reference - property declaration attributes - setter semantics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW2). Also, `assign` is the only possible choice since the other semantics only apply to objects, not primitives.

Comment: So, does ARC put `strong` by default for objects and `assign` for primitive types?

Answer (score 4):

Seems you need to read up on a certain subject here.
Check: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Check chapter 4 ;)
Here you will read that assign is fine with ARC.

Answer (score 0):

When ARC Enabled you can write synthesised properties for primitive data like(ex:BOOL).. 
@property(unsafe_unretained) bool isOn;